# c# validating a hashed password that's stored in an SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

I have been stumped on this for quite a few hours now. I have been experimenting with creating a login form to a simple app I'm developing.

I have successfully managed to salt/hash the passwords and upon creating a user account the login, hash and salt are all stored in separate columns of an SQL database table using an INSERT query.

What I now need to do is take the password input from the user at the login page and combine that with the stored salt value, rehash the combined pw+salt and compare them to the stored hash value to validate the user. I am using a SELECT query to try to achieve this but so far have been unsuccessful.

Here is my code:

```
///Gather the data from the SQL db, find the username, hash and salt values
        string ds = @"Data Source";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ds))
        {

///define a set of strings for the query, the login textbox, password textbox and the Hash Gen Algorithm
            string query = "SELECT Login, Hash, Salt FROM [Table] WHERE (Login=@Login, Hash=@Hash, Salt=@Salt)";
            string uname = logTXT.Text;
            string passw = pwTXT.Text;
            string hash = GenHash(passw, "@salt");

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", uname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hash", hash);

                cmd.Connection = con;
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if("@Hash" == hash)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
                }


            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how to make this happen successfully.

My question is this: How can I take the value of the SQL column that stores the password salt, and then add it to the user password input from the textbox (pwTXT.Text + stored pw salt) so that I can put the result through my hashing algorithm and then compare the values to validate the user?

EDIT: Thanks to Vlad Stryapko's answer I was able to get it working by using a slightly modified version and have successfully implemented the hashing algorithm and everything is working as it should. 
So correct/most helpful answer should go to him.

```
string ds = @"Data Source";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ds))
{
string query = "SELECT Salt FROM [Table] WHERE (Login=@Login)";
string uname = logTXT.Text;              

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    con.Open();    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", uname);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();   
    string salt = null;
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        salt = dr.GetString(0);
    }    
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not obvious? You've described the algorithm pretty accurately. Do you have an issue with reading from the db? Do you have an issue with combining the read result with the textbox?

Comment: hey thank you for the response, my problem is that I can't figure out how to get the value of the stored salt from the db, and combining this with the input from the textbox as you mentioned. I know the process I need to achieve with the algorithm but actually pulling the data from the db is proving troublesome for me. Any suggestions on what I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Please check my answer to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get the salt, based on your current code:

```
string ds = @"Data Source";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ds))
{
    string query = "SELECT Salt FROM [Table] WHERE (Login=@Login)";
    string uname = logTXT.Text;              

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();    
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", uname);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();   
        string salt = null;
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            salt = reader[0];
        }    
    }
}
```

Later on you can use the salt to pass it to your hashing function.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, have implemented this and it worked perfectly besides one part that I changed

you had: 
if (reader.Read()))
{
    salt = reader[0];
}

I used instead: 
if (dr.Read())
{
    salt = dr.GetString(0)
}

You definitely put me on the right track though, I now already have the hashing function and login working completely with your help. So thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The GenHash() function is being passed the string "@salt" instead of the actual salt.

You need to change your implementation to first query salt, then compute the hash, and then query one more time to compare the computed hash to the stored hash.

For a hash to give the same output, the password and the salt have to be the same.

As a side note, you probably should use PBKDF2 or Bcrypt instead of a simple hash like SHA or MD5.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I knew the string @Salt was wrong, it was part of my last effort to get it working (unsuccessfully). 

I'm trying to pull the value of the salt with the first query but am unsure how to achieve this. Is this done by using the Sqldatareader? What is the query needed to get the salt so I can use it to compute the hash?